# Confused about the maxWait option for LoDash's debounce method

Tags: javascript, lodash, debouncing

LoDash's [debounce](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) accepts an option `maxWait`.

From the docs:

> `[options.maxWait]` (number): The maximum time `func` is allowed to be delayed before it’s called.

I'm confused, isn't that just the same as using [throttle](http://lodash.com/docs#throttle)? What's the difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are a similar concept but quite different.

`maxWait` - the amount of time to wait before the function is called.

`throttle` - the amount of time to wait **between** calls.

`throttle` is used when you are calling a function multiple times and don't want it to be called too often.  `maxWait` is used when you are delaying execution of a single event.

**edit** adding a bit more detail here:

the difference between _throttle and _debounce is a bit subtle.

_debounce creates a function which:

> Creates a function that will delay the execution of func until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked.

while _throttle creates a function which:

> Creates a function that, when executed, will only call the func function at most once per every wait milliseconds.

_debounce actually allows subsequent calls to occur, but delays their processing, while _throttle actually disallows calls during the wait period.

You can debounce a function multiple times, delaying it theoretically indefinitely. `maxWait` can be used to ensure the function does eventually get called.

The `leading` and `trailing` options do not cause additional runs of the function; instead, they control when the function is executed.

Using `leading` causes the function to execute, and subsequent calls to be debounced.

Using `trailing` causes the function to execute at the end of the debounce, which could be less than the timeout.  Essentially, you are allowing the subsequent calls to happen as soon as the last debounce time ends, instead of forcing them to wait for their entire timeout if they started in the middle.

> Note: If leading and trailing options are true func will be called on the trailing edge of the timeout only if the the debounced function is invoked more than once during the wait timeout.

so, in theory if you used all 3 options (`leading`, `maxWait`, and `trailing`), the `maxWait` wouldn't happen because you would never exceed the wait period, and `trailing` would only happen if you called the function twice in the same wait period.

Comment: ok... What if I used `debounce` with `{leading:true,maxWait:100,trailing:true}` – if I then called the function loads of times, how many times would it actually run - three? (one for leading, one for maxWait, and one for trailing?)

Comment: The visualization for the `debounce` method on this blog post will help in understanding when `func` gets called: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: actually reviewing this and seeing the example on LoDash's docs again, @Claies last note that `maxWait` wouldn't happen is not entirely true. Setting `maxWait` ensures that the function is invoked once after the `maxWait` number is reached of repeated debounced calls

Comment: @d48 it's been more than a year since I wrote this answer, but I think what I was trying to say was that the use of the `leading` and `trailing` options together would pre-empt the `maxWait` option.  I'll review my test I had of this situation, but feel free to edit the answer if you feel it is incorrect or not clear.

Comment: Given that throttle is literally defined in terms of debounce with maxWait (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L10898), can we please unaccept or edit this answer? The distinctions that are made between “before” and “between” calls is nonsensical. Throttle is just debounce with a max wait, period.

Comment: @brainkim I converted the answer to Community Wiki, feel free to make any updates or changes necessary to correct any discrepancies.

Answer (score 18):

If you look at the source code, you will find that throttle actually is a thin wrapper for debounce. Throttle calls debounce using the maxWait property
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L10898-L10914

So if you call debounce with maxWait and trailing and leading set to true, it will have the same effect as calling throttle.